# Create a modified `equal?` function for use with RackUnit

Tags: racket, rackunit

I am writing a bunch of tests using `check-equal?` with objects that contain syntax objects that are not `eq?`. For the purposes of these tests, I am okay with saying that two syntax objects are equal if they're equal when given to `syntax->datum`. (Yes, I know that looses a lot of binding information, but for now, ensuring their datums are equal is good enough. I will test that the binding information is good later.)

If the two objects are not syntax objects, however, I want them to be equal if they are `equal?` to each other.

However, if those objects contain syntax objects in them at some recursive point, I want to test their equality on their datums, so I can't just do:

```
(define (my-equal? a b)
  (if (and (syntax? a) (syntax? b)
      (equal? (syntax->datum a) (syntax->datum b))
      (equal? a b)))
(define-binary-check (check-my-equal? my-equal? actual expected))
```

Because this will not do the recursive check.

I could handle the recursion myself, and only use `equal?` on primitives, but that would be paramount to implementing my own equality testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`equal?/recur`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html?q=equal%3F%2Frecur#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._equal~3f%2Frecur%29%29) to get this behavior. This function behaves like `equal?`, but takes a different function in the case of a recursive call. So you could potentially implement `my-equal?` like this:

```
(define (my-equal? actual expected)
  (if (and (syntax? actual) (syntax? expected))
      (equal? (syntax->datum actual) (syntax->datum expected))
      (equal?/recur actual expected my-equal?)))
```

However, note that because you are providing the recursive function, `equal?/recur` does not do any cycle detection for you. As such, you need to do it yourself. One easy way to do this is with parameters:

```
(define current-equal-visited (make-parameter set))
(define (my-equal? actual expected)
  (cond [(set-member? (current-equal-visited) (cons actual expected))
         #t]
        [(and (syntax? actual) (syntax? expected))
         (equal? (syntax->datum actual) (syntax->datum expected))]
        [else
         (parameterize ([current-equal-visited
                         (set-add (current-equal-visited) (cons actual expected))])
           (equal?/recur actual expected my-equal?))]))
```

And then, of course, as you noticed in your question, you can use `define-binary-check` to turn this procedure into something RackUnit can you.

```
(define-binary-check (check-my-equal? my-equal? actual expected))
```